# Weird squares show up with alpha blend

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I'm creating a transparent material but if I have alpha blend as blend mode, these weird squares show up.
I'm using Eevee but using Cycles the problem is fixed, but I need this for a Gltf model so it's not a problem with the rendering of the scene.

This is what I've understood until now:

The mesh doesn't matter since the error occurs with any mesh, even with a simple cube.

The squares have the same size as a face.

Switching to Alpha Harshed would fix the issue but I must keep Alpha Blend.

It's not a viewport bug because I see the same problem once I export the mesh in Substance Painter.

It's fixed by turning on backface culling but it wouldn't show the back faces anymore, so it's not a solution.

Does anybody know what's happening? I've been struggling with this for weeks but maybe there's an easy solution that I can't find.

Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem with and a known limitation of Alpha Blend. In your case it can be fixed by selecting one face pointing to +Y, pressing <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> to select all faces pointing in that direction, then <kbd>F3</kbd> "Sort Elements… Selected". Repeat for all sides of the cube:

[image]

(I did only 3 sides because of GIF size limitation but you get the idea; though if you intend the cube to be visible from other angles, it may be tricky to make it work consistently using alpha blend… Maybe you could use geometry nodes to resort the faces dynamically…)

Here's the best explanation I've seen on BSE, not sure if it's a duplicate of that question:

[Alpha blend issue (EEVEE)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/249695/60486)